# Why isn't enough to prove that a is an even number in this demonstration of \sqrt{2} not being rational?

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers

I was looking though [a demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuijxhzmDgc&feature=youtu.be) that $\sqrt{2}$ is a irrational number (it is in French) where the main points were:

- the reasoning is *ad absurdum*
- $\sqrt{2}$ is stated to be rational, therefore there exist numbers $a$ and $b$ which are relatively prime such that

$$\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}$$
$$b\sqrt{2} = a$$
$$2b^2 = a^2$$

From there it is derived that $a$ is even.

The demonstration then goes ahead to verify that $b$ is even as well.

Why isn't it enough to stop at the demonstration of $a$ being even? It means that it is divisible by $2$ and therefore not prime?

Is this because $a$ and $b$ must be relatively prime, so one needs to prove that $b$ is also <del>prime</del> (sorry I meant **even**, I realized my typo by the comments), and so that they have a common divider?

Comment: A lot of rational numbers have even numerator when expressed in  lowest terms.

Comment: To see where it goes wrong it's useful to try to apply the same argument to another case. You will see that you are able to prove that $\sqrt{4}$ is irrational if we were allowed to stop after showing that $a$ is even (if $\sqrt{4} = a/b$ then $4b^2 = a^2$ and $a$ has to be even).

Comment: "It means that it is divisible by 2 and therefore not prime?"  Who said that $a$ was prime?

Comment: Your confusion lies in the meaning of "relatively prime".  Neither $a$ nor $b$ need to be nor are expected to be prime.  They are only expected not to have any factors in common. Lots if not "most" rational numbers do not have prime numerators.

Answer (score 1):

Relative prime doesn't mean they are *prime*.  Relative prime means they have no factors in common.

A rational number is one that can be written as $\frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are both integers.  For example $\frac {10}{21}$.

If $a$ and $b$ have a common divisor, it can be factored out.  For example $\frac {50}{105} = \frac {5*10}{5*21} =\frac {10}{21}$.

So if $\sqrt 2 $ is rational, then there exist two integers with no common factors so that $\frac ab = \sqrt 2$.  There is *no* requirement that $a$ and $b$ be prime.

For example: $\frac {10}{21}$ is a rational number and $10$ and $21$ have no factors in common but neither of them are prime.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:**
>
> Take, for instance, $\dfrac{2}{7}$.